# NIC cards for ClearOS box (or other software proxy/firewall)?

Tags: nic, 3com, clearos

I am building a few ClearOS boxes, and am trying to use components I have available without purchasing anything (yet) if possible.

I have some 3com 3C905-TX cards, a 3C SOHO-100, some 3C905B-TX cards, some 3C905CX-TX-M then some other generic cards, for examples, some with a chipset of "RTL8169S-32", and some others.

Is there a writeup out there comparing cards in general, or other information I can refer to?
Or any thoughts you have on which ones I should use - or if they are all junk, thats helpful too!

So, if they are too old / junk, what should I be looking for in a card - features / technology to know if a card is good for performance vs. being just an average/junk card?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well they're all PCI 100Mbps NICs from over a decade ago so it's all a bit pointless trying to pick which one is 'best' as they'll all be equally creaky. If you want write-up you may need to use waybackmachine.com or buy some old magazines on ebay.

Basically they're all junk yes.

Comment: Can you recommend what I should look for in a card - features / similar to ensure I select a good modern nic card?

Comment: For 1Gbps I'd strongly suggest using a PCI-e based systemboard and NIC, but once you're in that territory then any brand and model will be fine so long as it's supported by your OS.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up getting some generic 1GB nics, realtek chipset based.  Seem to work well.